# How to prevent accidental double-tap dodge when changing directions?

Tags: movement, game-mechanics, input, gdscript, godot-3

```
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("forward") or Input.is_action_just_pressed("backward") or Input.is_action_just_pressed("left") or Input.is_action_just_pressed("right"):
      dash_count += 1
    if dash_count == 2 and dash_timer < double_press_time:
      horizontal_velocity = direction * dash_power * 2.5
```

This checks if the the movement inputs are being pressed, if yes... gain one 1 point in dash count... dash count returns to zero after 0.3 seconds

if dash count is 0, you can't dash... if dash count is 2, your character will dodge/dash in the direction of movement.

The system exists to allow dodging by simply double pressing the movement keys... but I also realized that is quite easy to dodge by mistake by simply switching directions....

How do I fix this without creating a different timer for every single input? Also I tried reducing the dodge timer, but after testing it with my brother, I realized around 0.25 and 0.3 seconds is the safest as even a child can manage to dodge correctly with this timer.

Comment: Maybe I read that wrong, but dash_count should only increase if you move in the same direction as the last input else reset the dash_count

Comment: @Zibelas it uses an or ||  which in godot is literally or  so for now it works by pressing any movement key combination really fast which at first i thought was super neat and very smarty from me because this way players could dodge diagonally in 360 directions... but after a few days (now) i noticed that it is very easy to dodge by mistake

Comment: Why do you need a new timer for every single input? A single extra timer that keeps track when the last input was is enough. Either the last input is close enough or not. After every new input that timer gets updated

Comment: Is your intent that dashing only occurs if a given direction is quickly double tapped? That seems to be the implication, but it's not directly stated. And if so, how do you want the system to react to repeated attempts to dash? There's no mention either way about cool downs, but being clear about all the requirements upfront makes it easer to get answers.

Comment: @Pikalek I want players to be able to double dash either by pressing the same movement key twice and thus dodge in a direction... or by pressing two movement keys twice in a succession and when it happens the players dodge diagonally, for example forward+forward means you dodge forward, forward+ left means you dodge diagonally to the left, which was my first intention.... but after more testing i realized that this method makes it easy for players to accidentaly dodge when switching directions very fast, players can still always walk or run in all directions but if they mash their keys

Comment: @Pikalek but if they mash their keys in a panic because they have to suddenly switch direction but don't need to dodge, like for example when doing some ingame parkour... they will instead dodge which can cause their own death as their end up either in a position they didn't want  or they wasted all their energy doing dodges that they didn't need to do.

Comment: If you go back to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75945029/402022 notice I kept track of the last direction (`old_move_dir`). I was using the dot product (`move_dir.dot(old_move_dir) > 0.0`) to allow the player to change direction while retaining the speed, but not do a half turn. I suggest you revisit that idea. You, of course, could me more restrictive than that if you need to.

Comment: Won't your problems why easier to solve if you have a dedicated dodge key?

Comment: @Zibelas I played tera again after almost a decade lately, each class  has so many skills the keyboard is barely enuff, like the sorcerer class has 5 i-frames skills and and a mana barrier....the slayer has 6 mobility skills... the warrior has 9 mobility skills....in my game there's already a secondary dodge "sliding" which is activated when you are already moving either by walking/running/sprinting or by using attacks that have movement incorparated and pressing C at the same time... And I also played guild wars 2 which saves keyboard buttons by using this double press to dodge system.

Comment: Its not about the amount of button. Dodging is a core mechanic in Lost Ark and you still have 15 buttons for skills but if you miss a single dodge in a boss fight, that is usually your death. Fights are first about dodging and spamming as many skills as possible in a small window. It depends on your game, but if the player has to dodge so rarely that panic happens when a dodge is needed , it feels frustrating when the dodge goes in the wrong direction because of direction smashing. Double press to dodge is not wrong, but different direction keys for dodge will be hard to fine tune.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As Theraot explaind in a comment](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/206221/how-to-prevent-accidental-double-tap-dodge-when-changing-directions/206254#comment375845_206221), you only need one additional variable, to store the previously tapped direction. Only activate the dodge if the latest tap is in the same direction as the previous.

```
if Input.is_action_just_pressed("forward") or Input.is_action_just_pressed("backward") or Input.is_action_just_pressed("left") or Input.is_action_just_pressed("right"):
    if tap_count == 0 or dash_timer > double_press_time:
        tap_count = 1
    else if tap_count == 1 and direction.dot(previous_direction) > 0.0:
        tap_count = 2
        horizontal_velocity = direction * dash_power * 2.5

previous_direction = direction
```